# Multi project in new windows in intelliJ with Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to open new project in new windows in IntelliJ IDE, cause in the first time I opened new project dont choose "Open in new Windows" and check "Dont ask again" so Now when I open new Project its open in my recent windows, I cannot use multi project in IntelliJ, so what I should do now ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Open project in new window:

[image]